# How to Get Payload Facebook Account in Python

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, payload

I want to create a Facebook script for an automatic process, such as following or liking
Via Requests Library
I used the following code to do this
But I'm facing a problem
Because base_payload
It only works with the cookies from which you obtained this “payload” by using the Fiddler program, but if you use cookies belonging to another account, this “payload” will not work with it because it contains variable data from one account to another.

I tried to extract the cookie's "payload" before performing the required action, for example, "follow"
Then, call the extracted “payload” to perform this operation
I was not able to extract the "payload". I want you to help me solve this problem

Explanation of this code:

- I have a file called List.txt that contains special cookies for new style Facebook pages owned by different accounts
- actor_id_input extracts the page ID from cookies
- xs_cookie also extracts a number that I found changed from one account to another and I found it in the cookies and extracted it

  - subscribee_id_input The ID of the account I want to follow
- The rest of the process is the reset process using cookies and payload to implement what is required, which is “follow up the account you created as an ID.”

```
import requests
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlencode

# Load cookies from the file 'List.txt'
with open('List.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    cookie_string = f.read().strip()

# Split the cookie string into individual cookies
cookies_dict = {}
for cookie in cookie_string.split(';'):
    parts = cookie.strip().split('=')
    if len(parts) >= 2:
        name = parts[0].strip()
        value = '='.join(parts[1:]).strip()
        cookies_dict[name] = value

# Extract actor_id from cookies
actor_id_input = cookies_dict.get('i_user')

# Extract xs_id from cookies
xs_cookie = cookies_dict.get('xs')
if xs_cookie:
    # Parse the xs_cookie to extract the xs_id
    xs_id_parts = xs_cookie.split('%3A')
    if len(xs_id_parts) >= 4:
        xs_id = xs_id_parts[3]
    else:
        xs_id = None
else:
    xs_id = None

subscribee_id_input = 100004172086745

# Create the Cookie header
cookies_header = '; '.join(f"{name}={value}" for name, value in cookies_dict.items())
headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Cookie': cookies_header.encode('latin-1', 'ignore').decode('latin-1'),
}
# Define the base payload string with placeholders for actor_id and subscribee_id
base_payload = (
    "av={actor_id}&__user={actor_id}&__a=1&__req=g&__hs=19611.HYP%3Acomet_pkg.2.1..2.1&dpr=1&__ccg=EXCELLENT&__rev=1008551887"
    "&__s=hhau1r%3A0jfo8h%3Acwkna7&__hsi=7277420207286186865&__dyn=7AzHxqUW13xt0mUyEqxenFwLBwopU98nwgUao4u5QdwSxucyUco5S3O2Saw8i2S1DwUx60DU1LVEtwMw65xO2OU7m2210wEwgolzUO0-E4a3a4oaEnxO0Bo7O2l2Utwwwi831wiE567Udo5qfK0zEkxe2GewyDwkUtxGm2SUbElxm3y3aexfxmu3W3y1MBx_y88E3qxWm2Sq2-azqwaW223908O3216xi4UdUcojxK2B0oobo8oC1hxB0qo4e16wWw"
    "&__csr=gZk6Qp5OnkQJXW8AAL9bRsRbq9aDnqshiZPtiRFjbQC-ykBZutl4muWRTFl9GHWpBKLRqyaprXAy4KKUCA4LVanJejh96aDK4pHxhrykFQFECEymXVpp-GBm8iF97-imayFXVrgymh3EVqJtoG-exO8x7GAbzECVoim4AleibKaK6p8KKUqxyUy9x3ybyAmcx-8BzWx2Eoy8tz9V8S4VUjwBByEaEDypKicDGjABxK58aU88jGcx51dbCiKQ58yaxW2WdyrwCGazUqzWyohmqq4oaoeUkwiUhwjaxi6Hx6udxu1wxC2eVEdE5K2e4UcE1uoS010VCw0MWw5Vw0bfu0-bw3EU0xC0vWt2p60BE1Jo38w4Dx28Bw4zzUbE2cw0AKg0oxw3YXRwaam1oBw9S0eyg2bw3lPQlypE5q9yFEaEW0ga07wO04-wdOswgw9W0pW1Jw6sg1MFE2vwoHG1Gw9O0rS0pKcBwfG0Qo0l8w"
    "&__comet_req=15&fb_dtsg=NAcPPvoFWnukCo3fe-rOtzuI4px0oexhQjYX4P8wX8sxPQcMHKcdKnQ%3A17%3A{xs_id}&jazoest=25717&lsd=O37ARDdy80pHLxTuIRZBAh&__spin_r=1008551887&__spin_b=trunk&__spin_t=1694406431"
    "&fb_api_caller_class=RelayModern&fb_api_req_friendly_name=CometUserFollowMutation&variables=%7B%22input%22%3A%7B%22attribution_id_v2%22%3A%22ProfileCometTimelineListViewRoot.react%2Ccomet.profile.timeline.list%2Cvia_cold_start%2C1694406431945%2C92948%2C250100865708545%2C%22%2C%22subscribe_location%22%3A%22PROFILE%22%2C%22subscribee_id%22%3A%22{subscribee_id}%22%2C%22actor_id%22%3A%22{actor_id}%22%2C%22client_mutation_id%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%22scale%22%3A1%7D&server_timestamps=true&doc_id=6128808860558189"
)

# Format the payload string with the user's inputs
formatted_payload = base_payload.format(xs_id=xs_id ,actor_id=actor_id_input, subscribee_id=subscribee_id_input)

# Now you can use `formatted_payload` in your request
response0 = requests.post("https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/", headers=headers, data=formatted_payload)
```

I tried to extract this payload through it
Do these steps

- Request the link to the account I want to “follow”
- Then extract the page’s html code and search in it for the required payload

But I did not find it in the page content